# Converting an SVN repository to SQL database

Tags: database, svn, repository

I have downloaded the svn repository of Atunes using TortoiseSVN. I would like to transfer the logs of activity of the developers to a SQL database, preferably an Oracle one. Is there any software that can help me do this?

Comment: Why? svn allows you to query the logs efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

- Use `svn log http://myrepo/etc --xml` to get an XML output.
- Pipe the output to a file, using whatever command line operating system you're on.
- [Import the XML to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005)